# in R- for all values that are TRUE, is the same row, previous column also TRUE?

Tags: r, logical-operators

## EDITED:

In R. I'm trying to generate a data frame full of logicals that tells me for all values that are TRUE, whether the same row in the previous column is also TRUE. The columns represent time points, and I want to know for any row that's true, is it the first instance of that row being true? Note- i only need it to look as far as one time point (column) though. If it was true three columns ago, but not on the last one, it's still considered a new instance.

## example data frame:

```
T1<- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
T2<- c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) 
T3<- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
df<- data.frame(cbind(T1,T2,T3)) 
df
```

looks like:

```
     T1    T2    T3
1  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
2  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
3 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

## since I'm asking about the previous column, need to add a null column at the beginning

```
df_w_null<-cbind("null_col"= logical(nrow(df)), df)
df_w_null
```

## looks like:

```
  null_col    T1    T2    T3
1    FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
2    FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
3    FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

## for each row, where TRUE, is it the first instance of TRUE? (is the previous column true? If yes, it's not a new instance, print false)

```
for (i in 2:ncol(df_w_null)){
  status[i]<- as.data.frame(apply((!df_w_null[,i, drop=FALSE] == df_w_null[,i-1, drop=FALSE]), 1, isTRUE))
  status<- data.frame(status)
  return(status)
}
```

looks like:

```
status[,2:ncol(df_w_null)]


1                 TRUE                  TRUE                TRUE
2                 TRUE                 FALSE                TRUE
3                FALSE                 FALSE                TRUE
```

```
#expected result:
1                 TRUE                 FALSE                TRUE
2                 TRUE                 FALSE                FALSE
3                FALSE                 FALSE                TRUE
```

Comment: Please note that boolean should not be quoted.  Also, in your example, where is the 'a' vector

Comment: The input example is not clear.  May be you need `cbind(df_w_null[1],df_w_null[,-1] == df_w_null[,-ncol(df_w_null)]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of little step going on here. First, the `data.frame` gets split up into pairs of columns, then those pairs of columns are checked to see whether they meet the requirement of `FALSE` then `TRUE` and then the resulting logical vectors are reassembled into a final `data.frame`.

```
as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(setNames(lapply(2:ncol(df_w_null), function(x) data.frame(df_w_null[x-1], df_w_null[x])), names(df_w_null)[-1]), 
       function(x) ifelse(x[,1] == F & x[,2] == T, T, F))))
     T1    T2    T3
1  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
2  TRUE FALSE FALSE
3 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a data frame with all values in the first column `FALSE`

```
df1 <- cbind(FALSE, df)
```

You would like a TRUE value whenever the column `i` is not TRUE (we're not interested in the last column, so `!df1[, -ncol(df1)]`) AND the column `i + 1` is TRUE (we're not interested in the first column, so `df1[, -1]`). We have

```
> (!df1[, -ncol(df1)]) & (df1[, -1])
        T1    T2    T3
[1,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: apologies - I have edited the question for clarity!

Comment: Simpler and faster than mine.